# C buffer overflow only when way out of range

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

Consider next test program:

```
char a[10];
strcpy(a, "test");
for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
  char b[2];
  strcpy(b, "tt");
  strcat(a, b);
}
printf("%d %d %s\n", strlen(a), sizeof(a),  a);
```

Output: 10 10 testtttttt.
Everything seems ok.

If i<7 the buffer is overflow, however there is no error. Output: 18 10 testtttttttttttttt. Program seems to be working.

If i<11 then we see an error "stack smashing detected"...

Why is that program doesn't prompt an error when i<7 ?

Comment: it's undefined behaviour if you access an array out of its limits

Comment: overflow always happens because b has only space for 2 chars and you copy 3 chars to it

Comment: Well, his program is undefined at least because of the assignment to b, right.  It is likely "work" accidentally on the strcpy(b,...) on most modern architectures because b is likely 32 or 64 bit aligned and has enough padding to have room for the terminating zero.  That just ends up confusing the OP, because that part "appears" to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If i<7 the buffer is overflow, however there is no error. Output: 18
>   10 testtttttttttttttt. Program seems to be working.

The reason is because its an **undefined behavior**. You can expect any value to appear since you are accessing an array out of its limits

You may check [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) for these scenarios

Your buffer variable is only allowing 10 characters, your argument is 11, increase your buffer to support your argument.

```
char a[10];
```

The error which you are getting i.e, Stack Smashing, that is a protection mechanism used by gcc to check buffer overflow errors.

Comment: I don't beleive Valgrind will detect the strcpy(b,...) as erroneous, since *b* is on the stack. Given the code fragment OP provided, it is likely that *a* is a local variable, too, so Valgrind likely won't detect the strcat as erroneous, either.   Our CheckPointer tool *will* detect both of these. See http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/MemorySafety/

Comment: @IraBaxter: Yes it will detect it with `--tool=exp-sgcheck` option.

Comment: How does that work? My understanding is the Valgrind tracks the status of bits/bytes and watches the machine instructions run (since it doesn't have the source).   Writes to bits/bytes outside the heap allocated space are thus "easy" to detect.  But bits/bytes in the stack frame are all "valid" places to read and write; writes outside the compiler allocated space on the stack is still usually on the stack. In particular, Valgrind can't know where padding is inserted in variables allocated in the stack.   So how does the detection work?

Answer (score 4):

What you are doing is undefined behaviour. Anything could happen. What you saw is just one possible outcome, that some automatic tool detected it quite late instead of instantly. Your code is wrong, any assumption what should happen is wrong, and asking for a "why" is pointless. With a different compiler, or with different compiler settings, or on a different day, the outcome could be completely different.

By the way, there is a buffer overflow when i = 0 since you are trying to copy two chars and a trailing zero byte into a buffer that only has space for two chars.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking why there is no Error:
The buffer overflow detection is a feature to help you, but there's absolutely no guaranty that it'll detect buffer overflows.